# Leave Cell Blank Until a Value Is Added

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a formula that calculates how many weeks are due (Cell C12) based on a due date I enter (Cell B12). I want to copy the formula in other rows on Column C but if I don't enter a due date in Column B some random number pops up on the Weeks Due column. How do I hide the formula in Column C until a due date is entered into Column B.

Updated spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: The sample isn't inclusive enough, let more of the spreadsheet to be in the screenshot. Also, what is the formula that you are using right now?

Comment: Updated a screen shot of the entire spreadsheet including the formula. I know I need to use an IF formula, but I can't wrap my head around what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add google sheets in your title when you are using Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to use is:

```
=IF(B12="","",($B$5-B12)/7)
```

You say `IF` cell `B12` is empty leave this cell empty, and if it contains something then do the calculation of `($B$5-B12)/7`

Comment: Thanks you sooooo much! Last question...is there a formula I can add to the STATUS Column to either show it being Overdue (if due date is passed today's date) or In Progress (if it has not yet passed todays' date)?

Comment: (If my answer answered your question please accept it as the answer.) I'm not sure I understand your last question, can you rephrase it, maybe with an example?

Comment: And what about the new question? Or maybe do a new Question on the site for it.

Comment: @vivamaymartian - you still haven't marked his answer as Accepted. Hover your mouse to the left of his answer, underneath the number with up/down arrows and click Accept.

Comment: This answer is more readable than what I used to use. I did the reverse, which is more confusing: `=IF(AND(B12<>"",B12>0),($B$5-B12)/7,"")`